# Find the IPsec ID and Secret id for my vpn connection

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, ipsec

Hi i'm using ubuntu and new to cisco vpn anyconnect client. I have installed it successfully and establish the connection by giving the user name and password. But it is showing the `timeout` error. So i have installed the vpn manually and tried to connect by using `vpnc-connect` and it is asking following things.

```
IPsec Gateway

IPsec ID

IPsec secret key

UserName 

Password
```

I'm only having user name and password for my vpn client. I really not aware of what we have to give for `Gateway` ,`IPsec ID` and `IPsec secret key`. I have used the `vpn-1.firehost.com` for gateway and for `ID and secret key` many forums used to convert the `pcf` file to `conf` file. But i couldn't find the pcf file too in my system. Can anyone explain me way to use the `Cisco VPN Client`, `IPsec Gateway`,`IPsec ID`,`IPsec secret key`.

Comment: You'll need to contact your VPN provider, and ask them for the details. If just anyone had the `secret key`, it wouldn't be very secret, would it?

Comment: @daxlerod If the secret key has to be known to connect to the VPN, then it's already "not a secret" among anyone that connects to the VPN.

Comment: Fair enough. Point stands though, it is doubtful anyone here can provide that information.

Comment: `openconnect` seems to be kind of realization of newer cisco anyconnect protocol. Try it instead of `vpnc` client. You still have to specify `authgroup` parameter instead of `IPsec ID` but no `IPsec secret key` required. `authgroup` is an index number of options server suggests in case of fail.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably confused because the GUI and command line versions uses different terms for the same things. According to http://man.cx/vpnc-connect(8):

```
−−gateway <ip/hostname>
  IP or host name of your IPSec gateway

−−id <ASCII string>
  Your group name in <ASCII string>
```

In other words: "IPsec gateway" is the VPN server and "IPsec id/key" refers to the so-called "group name/password". These things are somewhat mandatory configuration options when dealing with Cisco VPN thingys. Only your network admin can tell you what they should be set to.